# Mapbox polygons not displayed in ios 7 app

Tags: ios, mapkit, polygon, mapbox

I have designed my required map on https://www.mapbox.com/editor/ with several polygons, however when I load the same map using the id on my ios 7 test app the map is displayed ok but the polygons are not visible/added in the ios app.

Here is the code I am using which is the sample code given on the mapbox site...

```
RMMapboxSource *tileSource = [[RMMapboxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"ID_OF_MAPBOX_MAP"];

RMMapView *mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:tileSource];

[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

Have tried many different changes but at this point I am trying to figure out if this is actually supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you want for this is `-[RMMapboxSource initWithTileJSON:enablingDataOnMapView:]`. However, only points are automatically supported right now. The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/blob/3a1835bc8871dfba53befa20b41bddfdf1f4ca33/MapView/Map/RMMapboxSource.m#L112-L137) if you are interested in submitting a patch, however.